# opencv and python: how to use cv2.surf() with mask

Tags: python, opencv, image-recognition, feature-detection, surf

I am a newbie at opencv and python and am trying to collect keypoints and descriptors of faces within an image.

I am using HAAR cascade classifier with frontal face template to look for faces in an image. The HAAR cascade gives me a list of coordinates marking the faces in the image. I want to generate a "mask" at those coordinates so that I can use `cv2.surf()` to extract keypoints and descriptors within the masked region.

I don't know how to create that mask.

Try [this photo](http://danielctw.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/bukit-tinggi-trip-three-people-photo.jpg) as an example to work on.

Here is the code thus far:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Load image and convert to grayscale
img = cv2.imread('testPhoto.jpg')
imgg = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Look for faces in the image
cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml')
faceRegions = cascade.detectMultiScale(imgg)
```

After this I'd like to do the SURF extraction with a mask using `faceRegions`. Suppose `faceRegions` looks like this:

```
array([[488, 163,  91,  91],
       [357, 184,  93,  93],
       [154,  78, 107, 107]], dtype=int32)
```

There were three faces found in `imgg` so I want to create three separate masks at their specific locations with their particular width and height. And then have `cv2.surf()` look only in the masked regions. How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `faceRegions` you got denote the `x,y,width,height` of the faces. So you can simply set a ROI (Region of Interest) with these coordinates and send that rectangle as an image to your SURF function.

For eg:

```
face1 = imgg[y:y+height, x:x+width]
```

Now you can pass this `face1` to cv2.SURF() instead of passing the full image.

Comment: yes i figured as much and did that. thank you. though can you stil think of a way to place masks in specified regions of an image?

Comment: If it works for you, you can accept the answer and close it. Also, you can use same procedure to place it. for eg `img2[y:y+height, x:x+width] = face1` where img2 is your new image, y,x are new locations, but width and height should be same as that of your face1.